# PyRun_String returns a NoneType object

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x, visual-studio-2019, python-c-api

I'm writing a base64 function in c++.I want to use python to do the encode and returns the result to my c++ program.Here is my code:

```cpp
string EncodeBase64(string str)
{
    Py_Initialize();
    PyObject* ret1 = NULL;
    PyObject* ret2 = NULL;
    PyObject* main = PyImport_AddModule("__main__");
    PyObject* _g = PyModule_GetDict(main);
    PyObject* _l = PyDict_New();
    string py = "str(base64.b64encode('" + str + "'.encode('utf-8')), 'utf-8')";
    string pyb = "base64.b64encode('" + str + "'.encode('utf-8'))";
    char* rec = new char[8192];
    cout << "Request 1: " << py << endl;
    cout << "Request 2: " << pyb << endl;
    PyRun_SimpleString("import base64");
    ret1 = PyRun_String(py.c_str(), Py_file_input, _g, _l);
    main = PyImport_AddModule("__main__");
    _g = PyModule_GetDict(main);
    _l = PyDict_New();
    ret2 = PyRun_String(pyb.c_str(), Py_file_input, _g, _l);
    if (!ret1)
    {
        cout << "Can not get return value 1." << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Type of Return Value 1: " << ret1->ob_type->tp_name << endl;
    }
    if (!ret2)
    {
        cout << "Can not get return value 1." << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Type of Return Value 2: " << ret1->ob_type->tp_name << endl;
    }
    Py_Finalize();
    return "";
}
```

I input a string "123456",and the program outputs this:

```
Request 1: str(base64.b64encode('123456'.encode('utf-8')), 'utf-8')
Request 2: base64.b64encode('123456'.encode('utf-8'))
Type of Return Value 1: NoneType
Type of Return Value 2: NoneType
```

I tried to input the request strings to python,is runs fine.The result is as follows:

```
C:\Users\15819>python
Python 3.7.4 (tags/v3.7.4:e09359112e, Jul  8 2019, 20:34:20) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import base64
>>> str(base64.b64encode('123456'.encode('utf-8')), 'utf-8')
'MTIzNDU2'
>>> base64.b64encode('123456'.encode('utf-8'))
b'MTIzNDU2'
```

I want to know why does the return value of `PyRun_String` is `NoneType` and how to make it return the right value.
My envrionment information:

```
System: Windows 10 1909 x64
C++IDE: Visual Studio 2019 Professional
Python version: 3.7.4
Project Config: Release X64
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing a `start` parameter of [`Py_file_input`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/veryhigh.html#c.Py_file_input) is similar in effect to passing `'exec'` to [the `compile` built-in](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#compile); it means run it as if it were a complete module (think of it like asking for the "result" of `import modulename`; there is no "result").

Only expressions evaluate to a non-trivial/non-`None` result, not modules or statements, so for any `start` parameter but [`Py_eval_input`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/veryhigh.html#c.Py_eval_input) (equivalent to `'eval'` mode for `compile`), the result will always be `None` (it's only `None` because they need to return something to distinguish between `NULL` for failure and something else for success, and the `eval` mode necessitates a `PyObject*` return rather than a boolean). If you want to evaluate an expression and get the result, you must use `Py_eval_input` for your `start` parameter.